# angular как получить сообщение от сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

За пример возьмем форму регистрации.

back-end

```
app.post('/api/registration',
  function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.username == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send('Username not found'); //Пример 1
    }
    User.findOne({
      where: {email: req.body.email}
    }).then(function (foundUser) {
      if(foundUser) {
        return res.status(200).send('That email is already taken.'); //Пример 2
      } else {
        User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password)
      }).then(function (foundUser) {
        passport.authenticate('local', {
          successRedirect: '/',
          failureRedirect: '#!/login',
          failureFlash: true
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

front-end

```
$scope.signup = function() {
  $scope.newUser = {};
  $scope.newUser.username = $scope.regUsername;
  $scope.newUser.email = $scope.regEmail;
  $scope.newUser.password = $scope.regPwd;

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: $scope.url + 'registration',
    data: $scope.newUser
  }).then(function success(res) {
    console.log(res); //Пример 2
  }), function (res) {
    console.log(res); //Пример 1
  }
};
```

В первом случае, Пример 1 браузер получает ошибку

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/registration 400 (Bad Request)

сообщения Username not found не нашел ни где. Если сделать запрос через постман, там получаю и сообщение.

Во втором случае, Пример 2 браузер показывает сообщение

> Object {data: "That email is already taken.", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Моя задача получить сообщение об ошибке от сервера и на основании этой ошибки вывести системное сообщение или произвести какие то манипуляции на стороне клиента. Как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Посмотрите в res.data - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Я для себя реализовал это несколько иначе. API всегда отдает ответ 200 если он запрос принял и обработал, но если есть ошибки данных а не работы API, то он возращает массив error_msg где перечислены все ошибки. Angular же если есть error_msg обрашается к сервису (библиотека ошибок по внутренним кодам с текстовыми сообщениями) и выводит пользователю уже сообщение в браузере.